# Why "John lost his coat and his temper" has logically and grammatically different ideas?

Tags: figurative-language

Consider this quote first please.

> For instance, in a sentence “**John lost his coat and his temper**”, the
>   verb “lost” applies to both noun “coat” and “temper”. Losing a coat
>   and losing temper are **logically and grammatically different ideas** that
>   are brought together in the above-mentioned sentence.

The quote above is a discussion of the literary device [Zeugma](http://literarydevices.net/zeugma/)

> Zeugma, from Greek “yoking” or “bonding”, is a figure of speech in
>   which a word, usually a verb or an adjective, applies to more than one
>   noun, **blending together grammatically and logically different ideas**.

I understand why the example has logically different ideas, *but I do not know how they are grammatically different too*.

I could think of *losing a coat* as a concrete notion while *losing temper* as a non-literal one. However, I am not sure I do in terms of grammar.

Could it be **not** dropping the pronoun *his* in *his temper*? or *dropping* the verb *lost*?

Would adding the verb *lost* make it grammatical?: John lost his coat and **lost** his temper.

Comment: *To lose one's temper* is an idiom.

Comment: Zeugma is a special literary device used for humorous effect in fiction, but it isn't normally used in speech.

Comment: Of all the things I "lost", I miss my mind the most.

Comment: Cool question. I also agree with you in that it seems the verb used is grammatically fulfilling the same function but has a different logical meaning. Here's another example “[They] covered themselves with dust and glory.”

Comment: @V.V. True, but how does an idiom make it grammatically different? Out of curiosity, could someone give an example that is grammatical different but not an idiom?

Answer (score 1):

[Zeugma or syllepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma#Syllepsis) comes in several different shades: not all require grammatical inconsistency.  The example that you quote is a type called semantic syllepsis, where a single word is used with two other parts of a sentence but must be understood differently in relation to each.

It is generally used for dramatic or humorous effect, for example in this popular song:

> she made no reply, up her mind and a dash for the door - [Flanders and Swann, Have some Madeira my dear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Some_Madeira_M%27Dear)

.

> John lost his coat and his temper

In your example, the person loses two things: his coat and his temper. There are conceptual differences between them, starting with the fact that a coat is concrete and a temper is abstract, but grammatically there is **no difference at all** between these two things.

It is even debatable whether **lose** actually changes its meaning between the two different usages, as the expression **lose one's temper** relates to the original meaning of **temper**, which is [calm state of mind](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=temper). So, losing your temper means losing (in the normal sense) your calm state of mind.

Comment: Thanks JavaLatte. Could you check the question again. I edit it and I hope I clarified what I want, how the example in my quote have different grammatical ideas. Bonding illogical ideas is clear to me.

Comment: As JavaLatte has said, not all zeugma have **both** grammatical and logical inconsistencies. This one is logical only -- "lost" has two different definitions here, but if you read it prescriptively it follows all expected grammatical rules.

Comment: @Emmabee, your comment set me thinking: I am not convinced that **lose** does have different definitions in this sentence. I have updated my answer.