# Why is a place associated with an emotion?

Tags: grammar

> She sobs on the edge of both the runway and hysteria.

What does this sentence mean by" both the runway and hysteria "?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "John lost his coat and his temper" has logically and grammatically different ideas?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94925/why-john-lost-his-coat-and-his-temper-has-logically-and-grammatically-differen) See also [Name for using verb with different meanings for parts of its compound object.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175593/name-for-using-verb-with-different-meanings-for-parts-of-its-compound-object?rq=1)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the cited text is a facetious reference to the winner of the Miss America beauty contest back in the 90s, where the "runway" is the raised walkway that contestants paraded along in their swimsuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be on the edge of a thing - a road, a bridge, a cliff, etc, and also the word can mean at the beginning of a mental state - on the edge of giving up a task, of losing patience, of feeling something. She is literally on the edge of the real physical runway and also at the same time mentally approaching the state of hysteria.

Answer (score 2):

It's an example of **zeugma**, sometimes used for humorous effect as in the song [Have some Madeira, m'dear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Some_Madeira_M%27Dear).